# How come the matrix $I - A$ where $\|A\| < 1$ is nonsingular?

Tags: linear-algebra

As the title says, why is the matrix $I - A,$ where $I$ is the identity and $\|A\| < 1$, nonsingular?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $I-A$ is singular then there is a nonzero vector $v$ with $(I-A)v=0$, equivalently $Av=v$. But then we get a contradiction:
$$1 = \frac{|v|}{|v|} = \frac{|Av|}{|v|} \le |A| < 1$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The invere of $I-A$ is $\sum_n A^n$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** What can we say about the eigenvalues of $A$?

Alternatively, consider the "geometric series" for $\frac{1}{1-A}$, noting that the sum converges.

Alternatively, apply the Gersgorin circle theorem.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that $\|A\|=sup_{\|x|=1}\|Ax\| $

Suppose that $A$ is singular, then there is a $x\neq 0$ such that $Ax=0$, we can assume that $\|x\|=1$, then $(I-A)x=Ix=x$, so we got $\|(I-A)\|\geq\|x\|=1$.

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that.  You really ought to introduce a new variable for $I-A$ since using $A$ to mean $I-A$ is needlessly confusing :).